# I am trying to call my array function but i am getting an error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wrote a program that includes one `main()` function and 4 calling functions.

I start off with a random number generator to find the max value of an array. I assign the max value to the array. I find the specified amount of random numbers and put them into the array.

I now want to pass the array to a `void` function that prints the array. Instead, I get an error saying:

> line 61 [Error] expected primary-expression before ']' token

And the same thing for line 65.

What should I do in order to pass an array to my `void` print function?

Line 61: `print( "Random Values", array[], num );       //prints the array`

Line 65: `sort( array[], num );                             //sorts then prints the array`

```cpp
   #include <iostream>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <ctime>
   #include <cmath>

   using namespace std;

   const double lowerbound = 10;
   const double upperbound = 950;
   const int minimumvalues = 75;
   const int maximumvalues = 150;
   const int maximumvalues_file = 40;
   const int maxperline = 12;








/********* Put the function prototypes below this line *********/

   double randDouble();
   int buildRandom();
   void print( string, double, int );
   void sort( double, int );



   int main()
    {
        int loopcntrl, num;
        
        double randnum;

        num = buildRandom();    //assigns the random max value for the array to num
        
        double array[num];
        
        for ( loopcntrl = 0; loopcntrl <= num; loopcntrl++)     //assigns values to the array
            {
                randnum = randDouble();
                
                array[loopcntrl] = randnum;
            }
        
        print( "Random Values", array[], num );     //prints the array
        
        cout << endl;
        
        sort( array[], num );       //sorts then prints the array
        
        cout << endl;
        
        
        return 0;
    }

/***************************************************************
Function: double randDouble()
Use: this function chooses the numbers that are in the array using
a random value generator.
Returns: a random number.
***************************************************************/

    double randDouble()
    {
        srand(19);
        
        double num;
        
        num = lowerbound + ( rand() / maximumvalues / ( upperbound - lowerbound ));
        
        return ( num );
    }


/***************************************************************
Function: int buildRandom()
Use: This function assigns the array to a specific amount of elements
Returns: a number that shows the total amount of numbers in an array.
***************************************************************/

   int buildRandom ()
    {
        srand(19);
        
        int num;
        
        num = minimumvalues + ( rand() % ( maximumvalues - minimumvalues + 1 ));
        
        return ( num );
    }

/***************************************************************
Function: void print( string, double, int)
Use: This function prints out the array.
Returns: Nothing is returned.
***************************************************************/
    
   void print( string RandomValues, double array[], int numberOfValues )
    {
        int loopcntrl;
        
        double num;
        
        cout << RandomValues << endl << endl;
        
        for (loopcntrl = 0; loopcntrl <= (numberOfValues-1); loopcntrl++)
            {
                num = array[loopcntrl];
                
                //checks if 12 digits per line
                //it ends the line if there are
                
                if ( (loopcntrl % 12) == 0)
                    {
                        cout << endl;
                    }
                
                cout << setw(9) << right << fixed << setprecision(3) << num;
                
            }
    }
    
/***************************************************************
Function: void sort( double, int)
Use: This function sorts the array from smallest to largest.
Then it prints the array
Returns: Nothing is returned.
***************************************************************/    
    
   void sort( double array[], int numberOfValues )
    {
        int i, ii, min;
        
        double num, temp;
        
        for ( i = 0; i <= (numberOfValues - 1); i++)
            {
                min = i;
                for (ii = i+1; ii < numberOfValues; ii++)
                if (array[ii] < array[min])
                    {
                        min = ii;
                    }
                if (min = i)
                    {
                        temp = array[min];
                        array[min] = array[i];
                        array[i] = temp;
                    }
            }
        
        cout << "Sorted Random Values" << endl << endl;
        
        for (int a = 0; a <= (numberOfValues-1); a++)
            {
                num = array[a];
                
                if ( (a % 12) == 0)
                    {
                        cout << endl;
                    }
                
                cout << setw(9) << right << fixed << setprecision(3) << num;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function declarations and your function invocations are both wrong.

You need to change this:

```
void print( string, double, int );
void sort( double, int );
```

To this instead, which matches your function implementations:

```
void print( string, double[], int );
void sort( double[], int );
```

And, you need to change this:

```
print( "Random Values", array[], num );
sort( array[], num );
```

To this instead:

```
print( "Random Values", array, num );
sort( array, num );
```

---

There are other problems with your code:

In `main()`, you are creating `array` as a *variable-length array*, which is a [non-standard feature that you should avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/). When you need an array whose size is not known until runtime, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Also, in `randDouble()` and `buildRandom()`, you are re-seeding the RNG with the same seed every time, so `rand()` will return the same value every time.  You are not going to get any random values at all.  You need to call `srand()` only one time, ie at the beginning of `main()`.  A better solution would be to not use `rand()` at all, but instead use C++-style RNGs from the [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) library.